# Xdebug & PhpStorm - "No debug extension is loaded"

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to install Xdebug on a local server (WampServer) and use it with PhpStorm.

In WampServer, in my case, there are 3 `php.ini` files :

1. `wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\php.ini`
2. `wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.ini`
3. `wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini`

In PhpStorm, When I tried to validate the Debugger configuration for my Web Server, I got this :

[image]

But for the CLI Interpreter, I got this :

[image]

So my problem seems to be on one side, my local server uses the `apache/php.ini` and on the other side, PhpStorm points to the `php7.0.10\php.ini`.

My XDebug config in both `php.ini`:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="D:/Programs/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="D:/Programs/wamp64/tmp"
;xdebug.show_local_vars=1
;xdebug.max_nesting_level = -1
;xdebug.auto_trace=1
;xdebug.trace_output_dir="D:\backup\Johan\professionel\travail_web\env-wp\wp-sites\_xdebug\trace\"
```

So how to fix this ?

Comment: "*...and on the other side, PhpStorm points to the `php7.0.10\php.ini`"*. You have a typical situation (especially for Linux/MacOS) when PHP in CLI environment uses different php.ini than what it uses under Apache. PhpStorm does not point anywhere -- it's PHP itself uses that particular php.ini file. *"So how to fix this"* Add xdebug to both php.ini (if you need to debug both CLI scripts (that's where PHP Interpreter will be used when initiating debug from IDE) and web pages).

Comment: @LazyOne I already add the xdebug config in each php.ini without success. The error “No debug extension is loaded” is still there.

Comment: Your 2nd screenshot (CLI) shows that xdebug is there (v2.4.1). As for Apache one -- have you restarted Apache after making such changes? It may still be using old php.ini.